# Fetching preference value from plugin_customization.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

I created a `plugin_customization.ini` file & set default value of two fields of my preference page in it as:

```
com.test.pluginname/name=test
com.test.pluginname/contact=5555
```

I set the path of this `.ini` file in `VM argument` of my `Debug` configuration as 
`-Declipse.pluginCustomization=D:\pathTo\plugin_customization.ini`

When running the code I tried printing the value using

```
String name= BundleDefaultsScope.INSTANCE.getNode(id).get(PreferenceConstants.NAME, "");
String number= BundleDefaultsScope.INSTANCE.getNode(id).get(PreferenceConstants.NUMBER, "");
```

where id is plugin id. Using this i am unable to get the values set in `plugin_customization.ini` file.How to get those value??

Answer (score 0):

The values in the plugin_customization.ini set the instance scope preferences for the plugins so you need to use `InstanceScope.INSTANCE` (or `ScopedPreferenceStore`).

Comment: As an user, how can he verify that the parameter defined in **plugin_customization.ini** is effectively used by the application? 

By verifying in  **About Application => Installation Details => Configuration**. it seems that the defined parameter is not here.

Comment: @CongBangDO There is nothing that shows you that the value is being used - you just have to check that the preference is set as expected.